# Can you always find a regular sequence consisting of monomials?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field, and let $S=\mathbb{k}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$. Let $M$ be an $S$-module. A sequence $$f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_r$$ of polynomials in the maximal ideal $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle$ of $S$ is said to be a *regular* M-sequence if $M/\langle f_1,\ldots,f_r\rangle M\neq0$ and $f_i$ is a nonzerodivisor on $$M/\langle f_1,\ldots,f_{i-1}\rangle M$$ for each $1\leq i\leq r$. The *depth* of an $S$-module is the common length of the longest regular $M$-sequence.

Now, if $M$ is an $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $S$-module, one may assume that the polynomials $f_i$ in a regular $I$-sequence are homogeneous. In other words, it is always possible to find a regular sequence of length $depth\;M$ consisting of *homogeneous* polynomials.

However, when $M$ is $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded, it is *not* always possible to find a regular $M$-sequence consisting of monomials - contrary to what one would perhaps expect from the homogeneous case.

For example, consider $S=\mathbb{k}[x,y,z]$ and $M=S/\langle xyz\rangle$. Here $depth\; M=2$ but every monomial is a zerodivisor.

My question is: If you restrict yourself to the case when $M$ is not only a $\mathbb{Z}^n$-graded module but actually a monomial ideal (or stricter yet, a squarefree monomial ideal), is it always possible to find a regular $M$-sequence of length $depth\; M$ *consisting of monomials*?

Comment: Well, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the actual question. Could you explain what is happening when $S = k[x,y]$ and $M = (x)$ or $M = (xy)$? Since both are isomorphic to $S$, their depth is $2$.

Comment: @Youngsu I think the OP wants to know if there is a $S$-sequence consisting of $\operatorname{grade}I$ monomials in a monomial ideal $I$.